# How to create a file with a given size in Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line

For testing purposes I have to generate a file of a certain size (to test an upload limit).

What is a command to create a file of a certain size on Linux?

Comment: large size http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257844/quickly-create-a-large-file-on-a-linux-system

Answer (score 249, accepted):

For small files:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=upload_test bs=file_size count=1
```

Where `file_size` is the size of your test file in bytes.

For big files:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=upload_test bs=1M count=size_in_megabytes
```

Comment: Oh, that might be more efficient than my approach because it does it all in one block.  Good idea.

Comment: Actually, using a huge blocksize will perform much worse once it gets very big, as it will allocate and read that amount into memory before writing. If this is somethig like bs=4GiB you'll probably end up swapping.

Comment: What about if you use a file as a template and copy its beginning (with `head -c file_size > desired_file`) or its ending (with `tail -c file_size > desired_file`)? Would it be faster? It would also be "randomish".

Comment: `dd` has a limit of 2^32 for its values, so to create a file larger than 4 GB, there's a trick: `dd if=/dev/zero of=test bs=1M count=<size in megabytes>`.

Comment: See next answer for a better, quicker approach

Comment: @elegantdice it's not clear which answer is next, they can change their position

Comment: @vladkras true... i meant jørgensen answer, truncate and fallocate

Comment: Since you specified `bs` to be `1M` wouldn't that cause the parameter `count` to actually work with MiB(Mebibytes), instead of MB(Megabytes)?

Comment: Beware when using `dd` that if you use certain devices (e.g. `/dev/random`) it can terminate early resulting in a smaller file. (See here for differences between `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/324209/when-to-use-dev-random-vs-dev-urandom)

Comment: @DmytroSirenko about `2^32` is it documented? and about `dd if=/dev/zero of=test bs=1M count=<size in megabytes>` is according your experience or from other source? Thanks.

Answer (score 229):

Please, modern is easier, and faster. On Linux, (pick one)

```
truncate -s 10G foo
fallocate -l 5G bar
```

It *needs* to be stated that `truncate` on a file system supporting sparse files will create a sparse file and `fallocate` will not. A sparse file is one where the allocation units that make up the file are not *actually* allocated until used. The meta-data for the file *will* however take up some considerable space but likely nowhere near the actual size of the file. You should consult resources about sparse files for more information as there are advantages and disadvantages to this type of file. A non-sparse file has its blocks (allocation units) allocated ahead of time which means the space is reserved as far as the file system sees it. Also `fallocate` nor `truncate` will not set the contents of the file to a specified value *like* `dd`, instead the contents of a file allocated with `fallocate` or `truncate` may be any trash value that existed in the allocated units during creation and this behavior may or may not be desired. The `dd` is the slowest because it actually writes the value or chunk of data to the entire file stream as specified with it's command line options.

*This behavior could potentially be different - depending on file system used and conformance of that file system to any standard or specification. Therefore it is advised that proper research is done to ensure that the appropriate method is used.*

Comment: I tried `truncate`. It produced a zero-sized file using the syntax above. The 'man page' for `fallocate` says that the files it creates are full of empty `space` rather than data. It appears that it wouldn't be useful for some expected cases like "how long does it take to copy a 1G file".

Comment: fallocate seems to work fine for me. It creates a file the right size.

Comment: This is the best answer to this question.  The truncate/fallocate doesn't take long, because it doesn't write all the file's blocks.  But, if you were to then upload the resultant file somewhere, it would read zeroes for the entire thing.

Comment: If you want to run this under OSX, then you'll need to do this: `brew install coreutils`. This will add a **g** in front of the command, so you have to run it like this: `gtruncate -s 10G foo`. Hope this helps!

Comment: It seems that it does not work on a `NTFS` partition.

Comment: On my system (Ubuntu 16.04), `fallocate` fails with `fallocate: fallocate failed: Operation not supported` and leaves a 0 byte file. `truncate` fills with `^@` (`0x00`).

Comment: The disclaimer is important and has to be considered. I tried to use it together with df but that fails to count the files to the used part.

Comment: Both `truncate` and `fallocate` create sparse files, where the `dd` command creates a pre-allocated file (unless dd is used in combination with the `seek=...` option). These files are faster to create (on supportted filesystems), but require more CPU and IO on heavy reading and/or writing.

Comment: Tested on an ext4 file system: For `truncate` it seems that `df` does not care. For `fallocate` I did see an increase of used space (and decrease when I deleted the file). So **`fallocate`** does exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 44):

Just to follow up [Tom's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139261/how-to-create-a-file-with-a-given-size-in-linux#139338) post, you can use dd to create sparse files as well:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=the_file bs=1 count=0 seek=12345
```

This will create a file with a "hole" in it on most unixes - the data won't actually be written to disk, or take up any space until something other than zero is written into it.

Comment: Setting count=0 avoids having to subtract a byte from the file size.

Comment: with `count=0`, `bs * seek` becomes the file size

Answer (score 31):

Use this command:

```
dd if=$INPUT-FILE of=$OUTPUT-FILE bs=$BLOCK-SIZE count=$NUM-BLOCKS
```

To create a big (empty) file, set `$INPUT-FILE=/dev/zero`.
Total size of the file will be `$BLOCK-SIZE * $NUM-BLOCKS`.
New file created will be `$OUTPUT-FILE`.

Comment: Why did you ask the question?

Comment: I had to Google for the answer, so I put it here, so it could be discussed and kept up to date... you know, the point of the whole site?

Comment: I know people are voting @Grundlefleck down for XP whoring, but he does have a point - one of the ways to use this site as envisioned by Jeff and Joel is to put a question and answer for something you just discovered.

Comment: Thanks Paul. Though I'm not so bothered about the points, I am bothered about things I find on Google which may be flawed in some way I'd never find out about unless I asked here. People should feel free to make my Q/A community owned if they think I'm whoring, *shrugs*.

Comment: To quote from the faq's "It's also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own programming question, but pretend you're on Jeopardy: phrase it in the form of a question."

Comment: You might consider first checking if `$OUTPUT_FILE` already exists. Overwriting /etc/passwd with a 2GB file of zeros is discouraging ;-)

Comment: @Boldewyn: it's a good point, but I think using the command responsibly is implied ;-p

Comment: @PaulTomblin come one. we are not in a game to get XP for doing something :)

Answer (score 27):

On OSX (and Solaris, apparently), the `mkfile` command is available as well:

```
mkfile 10g big_file
```

This makes a 10 GB file named "big_file". Found this approach [here.](http://linuxcommando.blogspot.com/2008/02/create-file-of-given-size.html)

Comment: This is useful for situations such as OS X where the `truncate` and `fallocate` commands aren’t available. `dd` also works as described above although it’s `m` for megabytes, not `M`.

Comment: Wrong: This creates a 10 **GiB** file (=~ 10,7 GB).

Answer (score 17):

You can do it programmatically:

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int fd = creat("/tmp/foo.txt", 0644);
    ftruncate(fd, SIZE_IN_BYTES);
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

This approach is especially useful to subsequently [mmap](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mmap) the file into memory.

use the following command to check that the file has the correct size:

```
# du -B1 --apparent-size /tmp/foo.txt
```

**Be careful:**

```
# du /tmp/foo.txt
```

will probably print **0** because it is allocated as [Sparse file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file) if supported by your filesystem.

see also: [man 2 open](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open) and [man 2 truncate](http://linux.die.net/man/2/truncate)

Answer (score 13):

Some of these answers have you using `/dev/zero` for the source of your data.  If your testing network upload speeds, this may not be the best idea if your application is doing any compression, a file full of zeros compresses *really* well.  Using this command to generate the file

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=upload_test bs=10000 count=1
```

I could compress `upload_test` down to about 200 bytes.  So you could put yourself in a situation where you think your uploading a 10KB file but it would actually be much less.

What I suggest is using `/dev/urandom` instead of `/dev/zero`.  I couldn't compress the output of `/dev/urandom` very much at all.

Comment: My embedded system doesn't have `/dev/zero`, so `/dev/urandom` is good.

Answer (score 12):

you could do:

```
[dsm@localhost:~]$ perl -e 'print "\0" x 100' > filename.ext
```

Where you replace 100 with the number of bytes you want written.

Comment: And the actual filling byte as well. I need "\xff" and works fine. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 9):

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=my_file.txt count=12345
```

Comment: Remember that dd's default block size is 512 bytes, so this command will make a file 12345*512 bytes in size.

Answer (score 9):

This will generate 4 MB text file with random characters in current directory and its name "4mb.txt"
You can change parameters to generate different sizes and names.

```
base64 /dev/urandom | head -c 4000000 > 4mb.txt
```

Answer (score 9):

Use `fallocate` if you don't want to wait for disk.

Example:

```
fallocate -l 100G BigFile
```

Usage:

```
Usage:
 fallocate [options] <filename>

Preallocate space to, or deallocate space from a file.

Options:
 -c, --collapse-range remove a range from the file
 -d, --dig-holes      detect zeroes and replace with holes
 -i, --insert-range   insert a hole at range, shifting existing data
 -l, --length <num>   length for range operations, in bytes
 -n, --keep-size      maintain the apparent size of the file
 -o, --offset <num>   offset for range operations, in bytes
 -p, --punch-hole     replace a range with a hole (implies -n)
 -z, --zero-range     zero and ensure allocation of a range
 -x, --posix          use posix_fallocate(3) instead of fallocate(2)
 -v, --verbose        verbose mode

 -h, --help           display this help
 -V, --version        display version
```

Answer (score 6):

There are lots of answers, but none explained nicely what else can be done. Looking into [man pages for dd](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dd), it is possible to better specify the size of a file.

This is going to create /tmp/zero_big_data_file.bin filled with zeros, that has size of 20 megabytes :

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/zero_big_data_file.bin  bs=1M count=20
```

This is going to create /tmp/zero_1000bytes_data_file.bin filled with zeros, that has size of 1000 bytes :

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/zero_1000bytes_data_file.bin  bs=1kB count=1
```

or

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/zero_1000bytes_data_file.bin  bs=1000 count=1
```

---

- In all examples, bs is block size, and count is number of blocks
- BLOCKS and BYTES may be followed by the following multiplicative suffixes: c =1, w =2, b =512, kB =1000, K =1024, MB =1000*1000, M =1024*1024, xM =M GB =1000*1000*1000, G =1024*1024*1024, and so on for T, P, E, Z, Y.

Answer (score 4):

As shell command:

```
< /dev/zero head -c 1048576 >  output
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly run below command for quickly creating larger file with certain size
in linux

```
for i in {1..10};do fallocate -l 2G filename$i;done
```

explanation:-Above command will create 10 files with 10GB size in just few seconds.