# Create file with given size in Java

Tags: java, file

Is there an **efficient** way to create a file with a given size in Java?

In C it can be done with [ftruncate](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ftruncate) (see [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139261/how-to-create-a-file-with-a-given-size-in-linux#245239)).

Most people would just write **n** dummy bytes into the file, but there must be a faster way. I'm thinking of [ftruncate](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ftruncate) and also of [Sparse files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file)…

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Create a new [RandomAccessFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) and call the setLength method, specifying the desired file length.  The underlying JRE implementation should use the most efficient method available in your environment.

The following program

```
import java.io.*;

class Test {
     public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
           RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile("t", "rw");
           f.setLength(1024 * 1024 * 1024);
     }
}
```

on a Linux machine will allocate the space using the ftruncate(2)

```
6070  open("t", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0666)   = 4
6070  fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
6070  lseek(4, 0, SEEK_CUR)             = 0
6070  ftruncate(4, 1073741824)          = 0
```

while on a Solaris machine it will use the the F_FREESP64 function of the fcntl(2) system call.

```
/2:     open64("t", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0666)               = 14
/2:     fstat64(14, 0xFE4FF810)                         = 0
/2:     llseek(14, 0, SEEK_CUR)                         = 0
/2:     fcntl(14, F_FREESP64, 0xFE4FF998)               = 0
```

In both cases this will result in the creation of a sparse file.

Comment: How did you record these library call traces? ^^

Comment: They are system call traces.  I used strace(1) under Linux and truss(1) under Solaris.

Comment: In javadoc, it is written that "In this case, the contents of the extended portion of the file are not defined".
Does this still guaranties to be zeroed on windows and linux, or is there any efficient way to be sure all bytes are zeros?

Comment: I would expect that any OS worth its salt (this includes Windows and Linux) to zero the bytes, to avoid the leakage of older data belonging to another user.  However, I can think of scenarios where this would not be the case: old data belonging to the same process, or a small (J2ME) platform.

Comment: Brilliant. I used it to test an Android app under "SD card filled" conditions!

Comment: Interestingly `RandomAccessFile.setLength()` API also fills the file with zero's which can be very useful at times.

Comment: @Sandeep that is not correct. The Javadoc specifically says that 'the contents of the extended portion of the file are not defined'. The zeros may be the behaviour on a specific platform.

Comment: Does the above answer really work? The only thing created on my test system (a CentOS 5.6 VM) seems to be an EMPTY file that reports the "allocated" size via the length() method, which can be arbitrarily large, irrespective of available space. If you open the file and write a few characters, the file size changes to a few bytes. The getFreeSpace() method of the File class reports the same amount of available space before and after "creating" the file and you can use up the free disk space of the partition as if the created file was not there, irrespective of how large the preset length is.

Comment: A file of a given size, does not have to occupy that many bytes. Many systems support sparse files (this is what you are seeing), where parts of the file that are empty are not stored on disk.  Other systems may support compressed files, where the amount of storage used depends on how compressible are the file's contents.

Comment: Works as it is expected, but are there any ways to configure this approach to generate unique files (which MD5 values are different)? @DiomidisSpinellis

Comment: To make the files uniquely different create them with a different length, or tack a UUID at the beginning or at the end of the file.

Comment: I think this is a bad solution, the size on disk won't match the file length you want.

Comment: The original question specifically asked about creating a sparse file.  Sparse files by definition require less storage than their length.

Comment: @Kreender that is the whole point of the question

Answer (score 6):

Since Java 8, this method works on Linux and Windows :

```
final ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(2);
buf.rewind();

final OpenOption[] options = { StandardOpenOption.WRITE, StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW , StandardOpenOption.SPARSE };
final Path hugeFile = Paths.get("hugefile.txt");

try (final SeekableByteChannel channel = Files.newByteChannel(hugeFile, options);) {
    channel.position(HUGE_FILE_SIZE);
    channel.write(buf);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton @mandev . Worked like a charm !!

Answer (score 4):

You can open the file for writing, seek to offset (n-1), and write a single byte. The OS will automatically extend the file to the desired number of bytes.

Comment: Will the resulting file be sparse?

Comment: sk: In general, yes. In practice, this depends on the specifics of the underlying OS and might require some fiddling to make the file sparse.

Comment: On Unix and Linux, that will be a sparse file - one block of zero bytes apart from the single byte written (which might also be zero, of course).

Comment: On Windows (NTFS) and OS-X (HFS+) you will not get a sparse file.