# Most efficient way to create a large file (> 1GB)

Tags: java, file-io

I would like to know what is the most efficient way to create a very large dummy File in java.
The filesize should be just above 1GB. It will be used to unit test a method which only accepts files <= 1GB.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create file with given size in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245251/create-file-with-given-size-in-java)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Create a sparse file. That is, open a file, seek to a position above 1GB and write some bytes.

Relevant: [Create file with given size in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245251/create-file-with-given-size-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

Can't you make a mock which returns filesize of > 1GB? File IO doesn't sound very unit-testy to me (although that depends on what your idea of a unit test is).

Comment: I want to test a piece of code which loads a file from disk based on a filename and does some validation checks. So it has to be a real file.

Answer (score 1):

Made this function to create sparse files

```
private boolean createSparseFile(String filePath, Long fileSize) {
    boolean success = true;
    String command = "dd if=/dev/zero of=%s bs=1 count=1 seek=%s";
    String formmatedCommand = String.format(command, filePath, fileSize);
    String s;
    Process p;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(formmatedCommand);

        p.waitFor();
        p.destroy();
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        fail(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return success;
}
```