# android - pre-allocate space for a file before downloading it

Tags: android, file, space, sparse-file

how can i create a pre-allocated file on android? something like a sparse file ?

i need to make an applicaton that will download a large file , and i want to avoid having an out-of-space error while the download is commencing . my solution needs to support resuming and writing to both internal and external storage.

i've tried what is written here:
[Create file with given size in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245251/create-file-with-given-size-in-java)
but for some reason, none of those solutions worked.

Comment: don't just say didn't work for **some reason** , show the code you tried and the error you got, that way your more likey to get an answer

Comment: well i've tried almost the exact same code i've given in the link.

Comment: So you should show it in your question, in an Android example. Explain why it didn't work or what the log showed

Comment: never mind . got to do it again  ,and for some reason it works now . wonder what was the cause to my problems . i don't remember. sorry .

Comment: maybe it didn't work on some devices , and made the file have a 0 size of bytes. will need to check it further .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is odd. 
it works fine now . perhaps i've tested it in a wrong way.

here's a working code , for those who have problems with it :

```
final String path=getFilesDir().getParent()+"/t.txt";
RandomAccessFile newSparseFile=null;
try
  {
  new File(path).delete();
  newSparseFile=new RandomAccessFile(path,"rw");
  // create a 1MB file:
  newSparseFile.setLength(1024*1024);
  }
catch(final Exception e)
  {
  Log.e("DEBUG","error while creating file:"+e);
  }
finally
  {
  if(newSparseFile!=null)
    try
      {
      newSparseFile.close();
      Log.d("DEBUG","length:"+new File(path).length());
      }
    catch(final IOException e)
      {
      Log.e("DEBUG","error while closing file:"+e);
      }
  }
```

Comment: Seems unreliable at best, need a check to see if setLength worked, I find the size will remain 0 if there isn't enough space, or it will just be smaller than expected but not taking up all the disc space.

Comment: So have you found that it is at all reliable or is it completely useless? Any tests I've done haven't been promising...

Comment: i haven't used it recently. you are saying it doesn't work at all?

Comment: I haven't tested much, it seems to work with small file sizes. I tried using really big longs to make a few gigabyte sized file and instead it just did something like 400 bytes or 0 bytes.

Comment: @schwiz i've now tried it and it worked fine even with 1GB. i've updated the code to show that it's correct. if it doesn't work for you, maybe it works in a different way on different devices. maybe you could just jump in the file to the last byte and write something there, and go back. for me, the code i've written here works fine on galaxy S3 with Android 4.1.2 . for example, if i set the size to be 1GB (1024*1024*1024), it gets to be this size . i can even see the file size using the "total commander" app.

Comment: i have this all function just do it in ur mob and observe free or available free space in ur mobile it will not effected after creating this 1GB file dude

Comment: means if u see that file properties in sdcard then it is 1 GB but free space is not effected.... Y so plz help

Comment: @BhanuSharma have you tried writing to the end of the file as i've suggested?

Comment: yes, first time that one is blank then size is 1 GB but free space is not effected then i wrote something in that file like "abcd"  from   file.write(data.getBytes()); then that string is write but file size is also 1 GB actually i want to create blank file with some file size which decrease total free space see my question once   ...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21157058/create-jpeg-txt-any-type-file-which-requires-to-be-fixed-size-which-user-will-gi/21157368?noredirect=1#comment31850674_21157368

Comment: @BhanuSharma maybe on some devices the implementation is different? maybe the size left isn't affected by using this operation? weird...

Comment: u have something like i create one blank file with 1 Gb size and memory is also affected and later i write 1 GB content in that file plzz help

Comment: not currently. sorry. hope i will remember to check it out at home.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45431/discussion-between-bhanu-sharma-and-android-developer)