# How to create a file of specific size on sd card programatically

Tags: android, android-sdcard

Can some one please let me know how to create a file of specific size on sd card programatically.
I did tried shell command like this which is of no use,

```
try {
   Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("dd of=/mnt/extSdCard/output.dat bs=1 seek=1M count=0");
} catch (IOException e1) {

}
```

I did even try the same command in shell script and was not able to create the file.
I guess since my device is not rooted, this command did not work.

Any help regarding this highly appreciated.

-regards,
Manju

Comment: check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252332/android-pre-allocate-space-for-a-file-before-downloading-it

Comment: Hi android developer, Thanks for the info and that worked for me. Pls let me know how to accept your answer

Comment: i will now create a new answer that you will be able to tick as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [RandomAccessFile](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252332/android-pre-allocate-space-for-a-file-before-downloading-it).

Answer (score 0):

First you obtain prermission for External storage.
Edit the AndroidManifest.xml with the following line of code.

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

After that in java file write the following code.
    File fileName = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                "output.dat");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName )
    fos.write(bytes);