# create JPEG/txt any type file which requires to be fixed size which user will give

Tags: android, createfile

I want to create JPEG/TEXT/MP3 any type as per user requirement files which requires to be fixed size which will also give by user, e.g 500 KB,1 Mb whatever size and also on path in sdcard which will also provide by user. But I have no idea how to achieve that. Who can teach me how to make/create it??

Comment: Does the content have to be an actual jpeg/txt/mp3, or do you just need the extension?

Comment: actually i download something then first i have to occupy or reserve that space in sdcard so that i want this work

Answer (score 1):

Yes It is possible.

I am using below code to achieve such things.

```
class Test {
     public static void main(String args[]) {
          try {
               RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile("t.txt", "rw");
               f.setLength(1073741824);// 1073741824 bytes = 1 GB
               f.write("Hello I am writing this file".getBytes());
               f.close();
          } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: very different work did this code i already did this i create 1GB file but free memory size is not effected

Comment: Is it really work as a file and can i write something in this file after create it

Comment: Why not. If you can not do normal read and write operation then what is the use of creation of a file. You can write or read from such kind of file.

Comment: but i create 1GB file but free memory size is not effected

Comment: I edited my answer. It is creating 1 GB file and writing text also.

Comment: hardik i have this all function just do it in ur mob and observe free or available free space in ur mobile it will not effected after creating this 1GB file dude