# Creating a file of the desired memory size

Tags: java, arrays, file-io, size

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create file with given size in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245251/create-file-with-given-size-in-java)

Say, I want to create a file of size 1KB, will this approach work?
I create a java array like

```
char[] s = new char[1024]; //1KByte
```

and write it to a newly created *.txt file using a writer, will the size of the file be 1Kb precisely? If not, how should i create a file of the desired size?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245251/create-file-with-given-size-in-java this might help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java `char` type is 16-bits long and [OutputStreamWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html) objects are string-oriented, not byte-oriented. Depending on the [output encoding of the writer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#OutputStreamWriter%28java.io.OutputStream,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29), you could get e.g. a 2 KB file, or even something unpredictable on character sets with a variable number of bytes per character.

You would be better off using an [OutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html) directly, either with a `byte[]` or using [write(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#write%28int%29) in a loop. That would guarantee that you get what you are asking for.