# Generate a file of a specific size using Java's File

Tags: java

I have a Java test which uses `File` as follows to access a file:

```
File localFile = new File("/path/to/my/file/file.txt");
```

Because Im referencing a file in a particular location I must have that file in my project or the test will fail. Is there any I can generate a `File` of a specific size as part of my test?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245251/create-file-with-given-size-in-java) thread uses RandomAccessFile but I don't think that's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code.

```
        File file = new File("/home/ok.txt");
        RandomAccessFile rafile;
        try {
            rafile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
            rafile.setLength(1024);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```