# How to create a very large file cheaply using Python in Windows 7?

Tags: python, file, windows-7, filesystems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Quickly create large file on a windows system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982659/quickly-create-large-file-on-a-windows-system)

For testing purposes, I would like to be able to create and delete very large files (several GB's).   I have no need to write anything specific to them.  They could be random data.  Is there a way to generate a large file by simply allocating the space on disk?  If not, what is the quickest way to write such a file?  To create the file in a matter of a few seconds is desirable.

I need to do this within a Python script and am doing so on Windows 7.

Comment: @GWW: the OP asked for a Python solution, so it's not a duplicate.

Comment: Not a duplicate as this is clearly a Python question while the other one is more like a general question getting a shell answer.

Comment: @Nick Dandoulakis: There is a python solution to the question

Comment: @GWW: that doesn't make the question a duplicate. And probably it'd better to add that answer here.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This should work on ntfs filesystems, since they support [sparse files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file). It's almost instantaneous.

```
with open("file.to.create", "w") as file:
    file.truncate(10 ** 10)
```

The file will appearantly be filled with \x00 bytes, but those are in fact just created as needed when you read from the file. It uses almost no disk space (though it may *look* like it uses all 10 GB from the very beginning -- I've found no easy way to check the real file size in windows), and grows by allocating needed blocks when you write to it. AFAIK it's quite possible to create a sparse file that is much larger than the disk it resides on, though this may of course lead to trouble later on. :)

Beware: if you copy a sparse file, it may in the process expand to a non-sparse file (read "fake" \x00 bytes, write *real* \x00 bytes). This is a consequence of the fact that it *looks* just like an ordinary 10 GB file with null bytes in order to be "backward compatible" -- separate checks must be performed to reveal it as a sparse file. To successfully copy a sparse file and keep it a sparse file, two conditions must be met:

- the tool used to copy it must be "aware" of sparse files, and
- the filesystem it is copied to must support sparse files

For example, USB thumbdrives/pens are typically formatted with the old FAT filesystem by default, and it does *not* support sparse files. From testing, explorer of Windows XP appears not preserve sparse files when copying. [This tip](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Windows/microsoft.public.windows.file_system/2005-08/msg00152.html) suggests [Robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy) is up to the job, but I've not tested it.

Comment: +1 for this very interesting tips.

Comment: this seems to take a loooong time for me!!!

Comment: Right now this solution does create a large file, but it's not a sparse file. Windows (via NTFS and ReFS) requires a special flag (`FSCTL_SET_SPARSE`) to allow a file to be created as sparse. At the moment, `file.truncate` does not set that flag. https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/84091