# Creating a large file from Windows' commandline

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

On Mac I can create a random 5GB file like this

```
dd if=dev/urandom of=~/random5gb bs=1000000 count=5000
```

Is there an equivalent command in Windows XP? I want it to be able to run in a '.bat' file that I'm creating.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Quickly create large file on a windows system?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982659/quickly-create-large-file-on-a-windows-system)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
fsutil file createnew <filename> <length>
```

Comment: It works :). But do you know how to create random data within this file? (I need data inside the file so I can compare it with a copied version of itself after going through possible changes)

Comment: Sorry I should of been more pacific

Comment: @DanielW. I think that [RDFC](http://www.bertel.de/software/rdfc/index-en.html) fits for your purpose. It is freeware.

Comment: Thanks tyz :). It seems to be what I'm looking for