# Generate dummy files in bash

Tags: bash, dummy-data

I'd like to generate dummy files in bash. The content doesn't matter, if it was random it would be nice, but all the same byte is also acceptable.

My first attempt was the following command:

```
rm dummy.zip;
touch dummy.zip;
x=0;
while [ $x -lt 100000 ];
do echo a >> dummy.zip;
  x=`expr $x + 1`;
done;
```

The problem was its poor performance. I'm using GitBash on Windows, so it might be much faster under Linux but the script is obviously not optimal.

Could you suggest me a quicker and nice way to generate dummy (binary) files of given size?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can try `head` command:

```
$ head -c 100000 /dev/urandom >dummy
```

Comment: Is `/dev/urandom` available on GitBash+Windows?

Comment: @Samveen As far as I can tell: **yes**.

Comment: But /dev/urandom is slow if you want to create GBs of data

Answer (score 16):

You may use *dd* for this purpose:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1024 count=5 of=dummy
```

- if:= in file
- of:= out file
- bs:= block size

Note, that

```
 x=`expr $x + 1`;
```

isn't the most efficient way to calculation in bash. Do arithmetic integer calculation in double round parenthesis:

```
 x=$((x+1))
```

But for an incremented counter in a loop, there was the for-loop invented:

```
x=0;
while [ $x -lt 100000 ];
do echo a >> dummy.zip;
  x=`expr $x + 1`;
done;
```

in contrast to:

```
for  ((x=0; x<100000; ++x))
do
    echo a 
done >> dummy.zip
```

Here are 3 things to note:

- unlike the [ -case, you don't need the spacing inside the parens.
- you may use prefix (or postfix) increment here: ++x
- the redirection to the file is pulled out of the loop. Instead of 1000000 opening- and closing steps, the file is only opened once.

But there is still a more simple form of the for-loop:

```
for x in {0..100000}
do
    echo a 
done >> dummy.zip
```

Comment: `dd` is unavailable in GitBash on Windows, but thanks for the nice solution

Comment: [Here are some native ports for Win32 of the GNU-utils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/), very useful things among them (grep, sed, cat, tac, wc, ...), even if you choose to take another solution.

Answer (score 13):

This will generate a text file 100,000 bytes large:

```
yes 123456789 | head -10000 > dummy.file
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$ openssl rand -out random.tmp 1000000
```

Answer (score 6):

If your file system is ext4, btrfs, xfs or ocfs2, and if you don't care about the content you can use `fallocate`. It's the fastest method if you need big files.

```
fallocate -l 100KB dummy_100KB_file
```

See "[Quickly create a large file on a Linux system?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11779492/111036)" for more details.

Comment: this is the method. rest (dd cat yes etc) are just workarounds

Answer (score 1):

Possibly

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dummy10MBfile bs=1M count=10
```

Answer (score 0):

echo "To print the word in sequence from the file"
c=1
for w in `cat file`
do
    echo "$c . $w"
    c = `expr $c +1`
done

Answer (score 0):

Easy way:

make file test and put one line "test"

Then execute:

```
 cat test >> test
```

ctrl+c after a minute will result in plenty of gigabytes :)

Comment: I'm guessing the OP was looking for a non-manual way of doing this.

Comment: This was originally needed for precise testing, "nice way to generate dummy (binary) files of given size". Your solution is creative, but not precise. But thanks :-)