# Command for generating random content of any size in a file

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, command-line, command

I am looking for a command in Linux/Ubuntu for generating random content of any size into an empty file.

After the latter, I should use the same command to add new random text to another empty file.

I am run out ideas, Do anyone knows what command would be??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate dummy files in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9800405/generate-dummy-files-in-bash)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
base64 /dev/urandom | head -c 500 > file.txt
```

This command will write 500 random characters into file.txt.
Keep in mind that it will generate only letters, numbers, '+' and '/' characters.