# optimizing a file making program

Tags: java, optimization, writer

I currently have a working program that creates a file of any desired size by populating it with zeroes. This is great but the size of the files I need to do this for are Gigabytes, and this method would take forever in order do do this. If anyone can read this code over and offer tips to make this faster it would be appreciated.

```
public class fileMaker
{
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
 {
     fileMaker fp = new fileMaker();


     Writer output = null;
     File f = new File(args [1]);
     output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f, true));
     output.write("0");


     long size = fp.getFileSize(args[1]);

     long mem = Long.parseLong(args[0]) * 1073741824; //1 Gigabyte = 1073741824 bytes        


     while(size < mem)
     {
            output.write("0");


            output.flush();

            size = fp.getFileSize(args[1]);
            //System.out.println(size + " bytes completed out of " + mem);

            double avg = (double)size / mem * 100;

            System.out.println(avg + "% complete");

     }
     output.close();
     System.out.println("Finished at - " + size / 1073741824  + " Gigabytes");

 }


private long getFileSize(String fileName) 
{
    File file = new File(fileName);        
    if (!file.exists() || !file.isFile()) 
    {
        System.out.println("File does not exist");
        return -1;
    }
    return file.length();
}
```

}

Comment: ...that's like asking "how do I compress a 5gb file into 10kb"

Comment: Im asking for a faster way to populate the file

Comment: This code appears to be intentionally slow.

Comment: This may be a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: My approach would be to not do this in the first place. If the 4Gb is of rubbish "data", why write it out at all? It's not like it can be useful for anyone else.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257844/quickly-create-a-large-file-on-a-linux-system

Comment: @Jayan thanks that's pretty neat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Write more than one byte at a time. Write some multiple of 4096 bytes at a time.
2. Don't flush the stream after every write.
3. Instead of querying for the file size, just increment `size` every time you write.

Comment: thanks but how would I increment size?

Comment: Um, `size += how many bytes you wrote;`?

Comment: right thats what I was thinking , but if I'm writing to the file like this `output.write("0000000....")` how would I define that in `how many bytes you wrote`?

Comment: How many zeros did you put in the string? That is how many bytes you wrote.

Comment: okay so if I put 4096 zeroes, it would be `size += 4096` ?