# Fill up disk space in android device

Tags: android, linux, adb, diskspace, rom

I want to fill my device disk space with any dump data as part of stress testing.

I tried writing bytes into a file in external storage; obviously larger & more spacious the disk is longer it will take to get filled. [approx half a minute for 1GB]

Can we do anything from adb shell in this case? 
I checked creating dump data using *dd* command:

`dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/tempFiller.deleteMe bs=1024 count=$COUNT`

which basically copies dump data to destination file
Hence it also takes significant time. [approx 1 minute for 1GB]

Is there any faster approach? for a normal user / super user?

I also tried [fallocate, truncate & mkfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257844/quickly-create-a-large-file-on-a-linux-system) commands in adb shell, but none of these commands are found even inside su. I guess these are bash commands & installing bash shell in Android device will require the device to be rooted.

```
fallocate -l 10G gentoo_root.img
truncate -s 10M output.file
mkfile 10240m 10Gigfile
```

Comment: Have you tried drastically increasing the block size?

Comment: @SkyKelsey, yes I've tried in both approaches; when we write bytes in file programatically we need to take care about max size a bytearray can hold (Integer.MAX) & also the available heap to our app. In case of dd command as well if we try larger byte size at once, it doesn'e work; so maybe it also validates internally.

Comment: `adb shell dd if=/dev/zero of=/sdcard/deleteme bs=100m count=1024`

Answer (score 8):

I tried same thing in past.  My purpose was filling all memory on device. After experiments I found out that **dd** is the best way for writing big files. My best speed was when I used 1MB for block size.  I used 100MB files in order to have ability to balance free space on device.

Writing 100MB file:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=myfile.dat bs=1048576 count=100
```

Also for quick experiments I've used written free app [FillMemory](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.namstudio.android.tool.fillmemory.free)

Comment: another way of filling up the device is to run 'cat file1 >> file1' which on Android loops until you are out of disk space :)

Comment: How to clear after the job done?

Comment: @nhoxbypass, to remove file:  "adb shell" cd to your directory with file and  "rm myfile.dat"

Answer (score 1):

1GB in half a minute (30 seconds) is a write speed of over 30MB/s. Considering that the external storage on most Android devices these days is actually a [Secure Digital](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital) flash card, that speed could very well be the [maximum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital#Speeds) speed supported by either the card or the card interface of your device.

If using `dd` with a moderate block size (e.g. `bs=1M`) does not improve things, then chances are that you have just reached the limits of your current hardware.