# What is the fastest way to fill up disk space

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, perl

I've got a big disk worth few TBs ( `5 TBs` ) and i need fill up this disk space to about `95%`, this is a `linux centos` box.

I've tried dd as in

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=o_File1.img bs=209715200 count=1000
```

even tried running in a loop like

```
#!/bin/bash

count_=0
parallel_=10

BS=2097152000
COUNT=100
while [ $count_ -lt $parallel_ ]
do
        file="Dummy_DD_BS_"$BS"_$(date +%Y%M%d%H%m%s)_$count_.img"
        echo $file
        `dd if=/dev/zero of=$file bs=$BS count=$COUNT > /dev/null 2>&1 &`
        count_=$((count_+1))
done
```

but 5 TB seems like a hell lot.

is there a faster method, I'm Okay with any scripts python/perl/bash or anything, I'm looking for a fast optimized solution

**Edit:**

Okay so following the [quickly-create-a-large-file-on-a-linux-system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257844/quickly-create-a-large-file-on-a-linux-system)
 did not really solve much anything

> case 1 : `dd`

```
 time dd if=/dev/zero of=filename10 bs=1G count=10
    10+0 records in
    10+0 records out
    10737418240 bytes (11 GB) copied, 34.0468 s, 315 MB/s

    real    0m34.108s
    user    0m0.000s
    sys     0m13.498s
```

so an estimated around 3 - 4  hours to fill this 5 TB

> Case 2 : `fallocate`

```
 fallocate failed: Operation not supported 
   its a custom file system not the popular ext*
```

> Case 3 : `truncate`

```
   this is the weirdest ones
   it doesn't really fill the disk this seems to be just reserving the space for the file so definitely not suiting my requirements
```

so is there a better solution or I have to live with `dd` or create `smaller partition` to test this

Comment: A strong magnetic field? :D

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257844/quickly-create-a-large-file-on-a-linux-system

Comment: Like the one with Magneto ? ;)

Comment: Installing Windows...

Comment: Why do you want this? A much better way to test disk low conditions is to create a very small partition.

Answer (score 6):

```
  fallocate -l 25G file
```

Try this

Answer (score 1):

Try a [zip bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_bomb) 
You can probably download it from various places online