# How to create a file with ANY given size in Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line

I have read this question:
[How to create a file with a given size in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139261/how-to-create-a-file-with-a-given-size-in-linux)

But I havent got answer to my question.

I want to create a file of 372.07 MB,

I tried the following commands in Ubuntu 10.08:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=output.dat  bs=390143672  count=1
dd: memory exhausted
```

390143672=372.07*1024*1024

Is there any other methods?

Thanks a lot!

Edit:
How to view a file's size on Linux command line with decimal. I mean, the command line `ls -hl` just says: '373M' but the file is actually "372.07M".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Sparse file

```
dd of=output.dat bs=1 seek=390143672 count=0
```

This has the added benefit of **creating the file *sparse*** if the underlying filesystem supports that. This means, **no space is wasted** if some of the pages (_blocks) ever get written to and the file **creation is extremely quick**.

---

### Non-sparse (opaque) file:

> **Edit** since people have, *rightly* pointed out that sparse files have characteristics that could be disadvantageous in *some* scenarios, here is the sweet point:

You could use `fallocate` (in Debian present due to `util-linux`) instead:

```
fallocate -l 390143672 output.dat
```

This still has the benefit of not needing to *actually write* the blocks, so it is pretty much *as quick* as creating the sparse file, **but** it is *not sparse*. Best Of Both Worlds.

Comment: "extremely quick" but subsequent writes to the file are less predictable, and can fail if your partition filled up in the mean time. (Also careful with how backup tools handle your sparse files.) (But +1, it is a nice option.)

Comment: @sehe: I tried your command, but there seems to be something wrong. `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 199753560064 Nov  1 19:19 output.dat` and `ls -hl output.dat` gives `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 187G Nov  1 19:19 output.dat` 187G???? Crazy!

Comment: @DocWiki: **oops** fixed that. I was missing `bs=1`, sorry

Comment: @sehe I remember. Someone told me "Remember that dd's default block size is 512 bytes"

Comment: @Mat: fair enough. Showing a 'best of worlds' asnwer based on `fallocate` now (tested on debian)

Comment: @sehe: `fallocate -l 390143672 output.dat` gives
`fallocate: output.dat: fallocate failed: Operation not supported` on my Ubuntu 10.08. I am Googling for this error.

Comment: @DocWiki: You're apparently not using a filesystem that supports fast file allocation IOCTLs (like e.g. ext4)... That's unfortunate.

Answer (score 7):

Change your parameters:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=output.dat bs=1 count=390143672
```

otherwise `dd` tries to create a 370MB buffer in memory.

If you want to do it more efficiently, write the 372MB part first with large-ish blocks (say 1M), then write the tail part with 1 byte blocks by using the `seek` option to go to the end of the file first.

Ex:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=./output.dat bs=1M count=1
dd if=/dev/zero of=./output.dat seek=1M bs=1 count=42
```

Comment: ... I wonder why people prefer this version. It works, true, but it sure isn't optimal <whistle/>

Comment: Depends on what you goal is. Spares files are fun, but if you want to actually reserve space on the filesystem (maybe to have a better chance of getting large continuous chunks on disk), actually writing the file is helpful.

Comment: @Mat This solution takes too long on my laptop. So I have to kill it before it finishes.

Comment: @Matt Any example on using `seek` to add 0.07M to a file?

Comment: @Matt Thanks a lot. How to view a file's size on Linux command line with decimal. I mean, the command line `ls -hl` just says: '373M' but the file is actually "372.07M".

Comment: @DocWiki: just use `ls -l` to see the actual file size.

Comment: @Mat You could simply optimize like this: `dd if=/dev/zero bs=1 count=390143672 | dd of=output.dat bs=1M` instead. Much simpler

Comment: @sehe: we appear to have different concepts of what is "simple" :)

Comment: @Mat: simple is when the user has only **one** number to enter and no manual calculation involved. In your version, `count=42` is non-obvious and /hard/ to generalize in shell scripting.

Answer (score 1):

truncate - shrink or extend the size of a file to the specified size

The following example truncates putty.log from 298 bytes to 235 bytes.

```
root@ubuntu:~# ls -l putty.log 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 298 2013-10-11 03:01 putty.log
root@ubuntu:~# truncate putty.log -s 235
root@ubuntu:~# ls -l putty.log 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 235 2013-10-14 19:07 putty.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Swap count and bs. bs bytes will be in memory, so it can't be that big.