# Writing to c++ file till a specified file size is reached

Tags: c++, filesystems

I am writing a c++ program to write to a text file of a specified size. I initially create a text file of size specified say 2 KB, I want to keep writing to this file till the 2 KB limit is reached and that point notify the user. I am not sure what the best way is.
I am looking for a cross platform solution. Would something like libevent (http://libevent.org/) be good for this or am I missing something simpler.

Any advice/help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Loop, count, break if > threshold.

Comment: see related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965530/how-to-create-a-file-with-any-given-size-in-linux/7965560#7965560

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ofstream ofs("output.img", std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);
    ofs.seekp((2<<10) - 1);
    ofs.write("", 1);
}
```

- If you want to detect filepos, you could use `std::ofstream::tellp()`
- alternatively, sync + `stat` will be able to get up-to-date filesize without re-opening the file

Comment: @ababeel: then you've also written to it.

Comment: @ababeel: don't stop reading at the code. The rest of the answer contains hints on how to monitor file size!

Comment: I am going blind or low blood sugar (i dont know which). Thanks I had not read the last 2 lines. My apologies.

Comment: A little more help please I guess I cannot get the file size while I am writing to it. e.g. I am doing -> while(i++ < 1024) { outfile << 'A'; if (fileSize(file) > 1024) break; }. The fileSize seems to be zero. I tried getting the fileSize using various methods, stat, ifstream::tell etc. Please advise thanks.

Comment: `stat` requires a fsync (so the filesystem driver doesn't just tell you the last known size) and ifstream::tell doesn't sound right; You are _writing_ so an `ostream::tellp` would seem in order. Don't forget to `ofs << std::flush`. **Out of the box** why don't you look at memory mapping?