# Fastest way for generating fake files with given filesize

Tags: python, faker

I'm looking for fastest way to generate fake files for stress test where is a possibility to pass file size. Currently I'm using simple

`with open("{}".format(i), 'wb') as f: f.write(os.urandom(FILE_SIZE))`

but for my case, creating each file takes too long. It seems to me that the Faker library does not have the method to generate fake files

**EDIT:** The code below is just a part of whole script so any CMD/OS commands are not a solution for my problem.

Comment: @ Radosław Hryniewicki duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816059/create-file-of-particular-size-in-python

Comment: Not exacly. I'm looking for a faster solution to write non-spares files on disk if it exists.  In the topic you mention @Shamanu4 posted answers which doesn't resolve my issue. I have to truly write sth into files with  given filesize

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be better to use OS commands for that?

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/tmp/x bs=1M count=1
```

You could start that using `subprocess` module:

```
subprocess.check_call("dd if=/dev/urandom of=/tmp/y bs=1M count=1".split(" "))
```

Comment: No, because the snippet I paste is only part of the whole program. Inside my script there are a lof of conditions and exceptions which cannot be handled by simple OS command.

Comment: Why this command cannot be called this way `subprocess.check_call('dd if=/dev/urandom of=/tmp/y bs=1M count=1'.split(' '))`?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below to get command with explanation and then run the same command in for loop.

[How to create a file with ANY given size in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965530/how-to-create-a-file-with-any-given-size-in-linux)