# How to truncate an existing and opened file using Ansible?

Tags: ansible, rhel, rhel7

I like to truncate or resize an already existing file which is opened and used by an other application. In example, the disk may be cluttered with log files taking up large amounts of space over time like `/var/log/secure`.

In plain Linux the equivalent would be

```
truncate -s 0 /var/log/secure
dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/log/secure bs=1M count=0
echo > /var/log/secure
```

according

- [How to empty ("truncate") a file on Linux that already exists and is protected in someway?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423281/)
- [How to create a file with a given size in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139261/)
- [How to create a file with ANY given size in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965530)

and via `tail -F /var/log/secure` each would result into an

```
==> /var/log/secure <==
tail: /var/log/secure: file truncated
tail: /var/log/secure: file truncated
tail: /var/log/secure: file truncated
```

instead of

```
==> /var/log/secure <==
tail: ‘/var/log/secure’ has been replaced;  following end of new file
```

After some testing it seems that all in Ansible v2.9 available modules (`file`, `lineinfile`, `copy`, etc.) replace the existing file with a new empty one, but not truncating or resizing and resulting into the already mentioned

```
==> /var/log/secure <==
tail: ‘/var/log/secure’ has been replaced;  following end of new file
```

I am aware that rotating, compressing and removing logs files with via `logrotate` might be a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Ansible Issue #[902](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/902) wasn't implemented in that way.

However, as of Ansible v3.0.0, with [`filesize`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/filesize_module.html)_module, a simple wrapper around `dd` to create, extend or truncate a file, given its size, was introduced.

It can be used to manage swap files (that require contiguous blocks) or alternatively, huge sparse files.

See [`filesize.py`](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/blob/main/plugins/modules/filesize.py) under `/ansible-collections/community.general/blob/main/plugins/modules/` for more information.