# Create a large file with a given size with a pattern in Linux

Tags: linux, file, large-files

In Linux how can I create a large file with a given text or hex pattern (Like DEADBEEFDEADBEEFDEADBEEF ....)

I know dd can be used to create large files but it doesn't write desired text or hex pattern

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/tmp/bigfile bs=blocksize count=size
```

or

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/bigfile bs=blocksize count=size
```

[Quickly create a large file on a Linux system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257844/quickly-create-a-large-file-on-a-linux-system)

[How to create a file with a given size in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139261/how-to-create-a-file-with-a-given-size-in-linux)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
while true ; do printf "DEADBEEF"; done | dd of=/tmp/bigfile bs=blocksize count=size iflag=fullblock
```

Comment: Or `yes DEADBEEF | tr -d \\n | dd ...`

Comment: `while true ; do printf "\xDE\xAD\xBE\xEF"; done | dd of=/tmp/file bs=1c count=32`

Answer (score -1):

If your intention is to achieve a scrambled data and not random.

```
shuf folder/* | dd of=target.txt bs=1K count=2048
```

to get a 2MB sample file which you can then shorten or invoke the command above again with different numbers for count

```
folder/* will contain files with your patterns
```

Or as an alternative you can have your hexadecimal values stored in a single file in separate lines and use `shuf` to shuffle them based on your need and fill them

```
shuf -n 100 source.txt | dd of=target.txt bs=1K count=2048
```

Or you can just dump it in `dd` as

```
dd if=source.txt of=target.txt bs=1K count=2048
```

[Shuffle Documentation](https://shapeshed.com/unix-shuf/)

Comment: Sorry that did not work. source file had 4 bytes (DEADBEEF)