# How can I create a 10-megabyte binary file on linux?

Tags: c, linux, file, binary

I want to create the file to implement a I/O benchmark on linux.

Thanks in advance, Antonio

Comment: See this answer over at the Unix StackExchange: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101332/generate-file-of-a-certain-size

Comment: There is the link shared above by @Blaze with the solution you want. In addition there are several other links solving this same problem. With a quick search for Satckoverflow you will find several answers.

Comment: Another link inside Stackoverflow that solves the same thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139261/how-to-create-a-file-with-a-given-size-in-linux

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a filesystem which supports it, you can do this with `fallocate`. Here is the command line version

```
/tmp/tmp.tO6EDnuWXT λ > fallocate -l 10MiB derp
/tmp/tmp.tO6EDnuWXT λ > du derp
10240   derp
```

There is also a C API for this. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html

Answer (score 0):

If the contents of the file do not matter, you can do something like:

```
dd if=/dev/random of=./derp bs=1024 count=10000
```

`bs` is the block size, so in the above example I am creating the file in 1024 (1K) chunks, and `count` is how often I do this (1K * 10000 = 10M).  See https://www.linuxnix.com/what-you-should-know-about-linux-dd-command/ for more examples

Comment: I'd suggest using */dev/urandom*, so that it doesn't get stuck if there's not enough entropy.

Comment: You might also want to update your answer (although */dev/zero* from the other questions/answers would make more sense).